# How can i call payment array ? using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

How can i call payment array ? using retrofit

> How can deal with second array objects i have successfully done with
>   data but i have no idea how to call second array object please anybody
>   can help me with that...i am new in retrofit.

This is sample code which i have used in adapter class for retrieve data array object

```
public class InProgress_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InProgress_Adapter.InProgressViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Data_Inprogress> modelRecyclerArrayList;
    Context ctx;


    public InProgress_Adapter( Context ctx, List<Data_Inprogress> modelRecyclerArrayList) {

        this.inflater = inflater.from(ctx);
        this.modelRecyclerArrayList = modelRecyclerArrayList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InProgressViewHolder holder, int i) {

       holder.location1.setText(modelRecyclerArrayList.get(i).getLocaion());
```

**json data**

```
 {
  "status": "Success",
  "message": "10 results found.",
  "data": [
    {
      "work_order_id": 1,
      "description": "Desc-1",
      "locaion": "Locaion-1",
      "date": "0-01-2020",
      "duration": "1 days",
      "user_name": "User name-1",
      "user_address": "User address-1",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 0,
          "date": "0-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 2,
      "description": "Desc-2",
      "locaion": "Locaion-2",
      "date": "1-01-2020",
      "duration": "2 days",
      "user_name": "User name-2",
      "user_address": "User address-2",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 1,
          "date": "1-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 3,
      "description": "Desc-3",
      "locaion": "Locaion-3",
      "date": "2-01-2020",
      "duration": "3 days",
      "user_name": "User name-3",
      "user_address": "User address-3",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 2,
          "date": "2-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 4,
      "description": "Desc-4",
      "locaion": "Locaion-4",
      "date": "3-01-2020",
      "duration": "4 days",
      "user_name": "User name-4",
      "user_address": "User address-4",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 3,
          "date": "3-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 5,
      "description": "Desc-5",
      "locaion": "Locaion-5",
      "date": "4-01-2020",
      "duration": "5 days",
      "user_name": "User name-5",
      "user_address": "User address-5",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 4,
          "date": "4-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 8
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 6,
      "description": "Desc-6",
      "locaion": "Locaion-6",
      "date": "5-01-2020",
      "duration": "6 days",
      "user_name": "User name-6",
      "user_address": "User address-6",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 5,
          "date": "5-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "work_order_id": 7,
      "description": "Desc-7",
      "locaion": "Locaion-7",
      "date": "6-01-2020",
      "duration": "7 days",
      "user_name": "User name-7",
      "user_address": "User address-7",
      "payment_details": [
        {
          "amount": 6,
          "date": "6-01-2020",
          "payment_method": "Cash",
          "balance": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: please format your code. its hard to read.

Comment: really don't understand what you want :((

Comment: {
    "status": "Success",
    "message": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "work_order_id": 1,
            "description": "Desc-1",
            "locaion": "Locai-1",
            "date": "0-01-2020",
            "duration": "1 days",
            "user_name": "User name-1",
            "user_address": "User address-1",
            "payment_details": [
                {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "date": "0-01-2020",
                    "payment_method": "Cash",
                    "balance": 0
                }
            ]
        }

Comment: this is response

Comment: sir, above InProgress_Adapter is my adapter class and i have posted some codes which have only constructer and onBindViewHolder method and after that i have posted response which i get from server,,so i have succesfully done with data array but i am unable to deal with second array (payment method) please look at that.......